# A javascript parser could collect information of its original format?

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to make a tool that can generate html file from javascript source code, and display the code with syntax highlight in it. I want to keep exactly the same format of the code(comments, newlines, blanks) in the HTML. I tried babel-parser/traverse, but it drops those tokens when building AST(and babel-generator just use least number of blanks when generating code). Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You could use something like https://highlightjs.org/ instead.

Comment: YenvY: I've never used esprima, but it's documentation suggests that [syntax highlighting](https://esprima.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/lexical-analysis.html#example-syntax-highlighting) is one of its anticipated use cases. Run as a lexical analyser, it can be requested to return comments but not whitespace (afaik), so you'll still need to extract the whitespace from the original string.

Comment: @rici yeah I know how to make this now. There are options(both esprima and babel/parser) that provides an array of all tokens after parsing. The array contains all tokens include punctuators, blanks and identifiers， all I have to do is to corrdinate these tokens my self with their "ranges" property and extract keywords from identifiers according to their literal value. Comments are provided separately, can be handled in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

> A javascript parser could collect information of its original format?

Yes it *could*. For executing the code afterwards, this is not necessary thats why some parsers drop any information about the underlying sourcecode as it is never needed. However for JavaScript parsers there is a community agreement on how to store the AST called ESTree, and that [specifies](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md#identifier) that every node of the tree has a `loc` property containing the `start` and `end`  of a certain node in the sourcecode.

> Are there any alternatives?

One of those parsers that creates such an ESTree is [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/blob/master/README.md), but there are probably many more.

Comment: How are  comments accommodated in an  ESTree?

Comment: @rici they arent part of it

Comment: So it doesn't provide what OP is looking for, right?

Comment: @rici it still does, anything that is not in the tree is a comment

Answer (score 0):

You hardly need a parser or an AST to do what you want.

If I understand your goal, all you are really doing is highlighting the tokens in the languages differently, and preserving their relative position with respect to the left margin.

For that, all you need to do is extract the tokens and track the starting column number of each token.   You can hand-build such a lexer to JavaScript fairly easily; string literal tokens will be the messiest because of escaped characters.   You can use a lexer generator such as flex, or you could hand-roll your own use ad hoc processing and/or regexes (which is what flex let you do in an organized way).   Going this way you can process blanks to help track column numbers, and capture comments so you can reproduce them.

If you use flex, you can supply a bit of code to execute when each token is recognized; that would spit out your html.  If you build the lexer by ad hoc methods, you will still have the HTML generation opportunity just scattered around.

You can likely take the  source of an open source parser, throw away the parser part, and fix up the lexer part, if you want to jump start this process.

Comment: Regex literals are more complex than strings, partly because you need to figure out when a `/` is an operator and when it delimits a regex. Another complication in recent EcmaScript versions is [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which require recursive lexing.

Comment: Interesting. Older ECMASCript  "standards" defined ECMAScript regex literals *for lexing purposes* in a pretty simple form that in fact you could accept with a regex :-}   I don't know about template literal, sigh, some new bit of silliness every day.  Yes, that would require a more sophisticated lexer, but its still just a lexer.  If OP was trying to avoid work, he could simply go find a JavaScript prettifier and be done with it.

Comment: You can certainly accept a regex literal with a regex, once you know where it starts. It's slightly more complicated than the string literal regex, because you also have to allow `/` characters inside character classes. But none of that helps you decide when to lex `/` (or `/=`) as an operator and when to treat it as the start of a regex literal. For that you need to at least know the previous token. All this stuff is very easy to get wrong, but I suppose prettyprinters aren't going to kill anyone if they miscolour something :-)

Comment: Yes, I've written lexers for ECMAScript.  We solve the problem by give the lexer two major modes summarized best as  "regex literal can occur now" and "regex literal cannot occur now" and switching between those states depending the last token seen (so it in effect knows what the last token was).  This isn't particularly hard to organize.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected approach, I believe, and it would be totally straight-forward were it not for semi-reserved words. Anyway, my original very minor point was that it's (even) messier than string literals.